# Android App Crashed after keeping Scroll View

Tags: android, android-layout

I was trying to create an android app. When i used a Scroll view, the app crashed. There are ten buttons in the layout
My XML code is as follows.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="508dp"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pregnancy"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/pregnancy"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancer"
        android:background="@drawable/cancer"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pregnancy"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/kids"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/pregnancy"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pregnancy"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="@drawable/pediatrics"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cardiology"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/kids"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="@drawable/cardiologist"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/kids"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/cancer"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/neurology"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/neurologista"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/kids"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/kids"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ortho"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ortopedia"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/neurology"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/neurology"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cardiology"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dental"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dental"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/neurology"
        android:layout_below="@+id/neurology"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ent"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ent"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ortho"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/dental"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/medicine"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/medicine"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/dental"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dental"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dermatology"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dermatology"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/medicine"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ent"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="" />


</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I need these ten buttons to be in my layout. 
Can someone tell me why this happened? Thanks in advance

Following is the logcat report

```
    04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.doctorlive/com.example.doctorlive.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at com.example.doctorlive.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  ... 11 more
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  ... 25 more
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:503)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:356)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:800)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2105)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3364)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:612)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:103)
04-04 05:23:57.483: E/AndroidRuntime(939):  ... 28 more
```

Comment: "When i used a Scroll view, the app crashed" Post the stacktrace from the crash so we can try and find the error

Comment: i didn't get you. I have tested it in my mobile.

Comment: Post error logs

Comment: Logcat error logs, no?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces.html

Comment: @AndrewBrooke Logcat error logs has been added

Comment: @FerdousAhamed Logcat error logs added

Comment: @EsatIBIS logcat erroe logs added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:503)
 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:356)
 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:800)
 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2105)
 at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
 at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3364)
 at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:612)
 at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
 at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:103)
```

You have a crash because of `OutOfMemoryError`.

You have given a very huge background drawable to your `Button`. Downsample it.

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: By an image converter. Change the resolution.

Comment: i didnt get you. can you please explain?

Comment: are yo about to say that the image size are too huge?

Comment: Google is your friend "convert image to lower resolution".

Comment: Yes, they apparently are.

Comment: That worked for me. Thank you. I'm accepting your answer

Answer (score 0):

From attached log, it seems that app crash caused by `OutOfMemoryError`.

Try to use `lower resolution image` for `Button` background or use `Glide` or `Picasso` library to load large images.

> ```
> Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.YOUR_DRAWABLE_IMAGE).into(YOUR_VIEW);
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.YOUR_DRAWABLE_IMAGE).into(YOUR_VIEW);
> ```

**See documentation:**

1. Glide:  https://github.com/bumptech/glide
2. Picasso: http://square.github.io/picasso/